# Print PDF file using Xamarin forms

Tags: pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, printdocument

I am printing a Pdf file via print services.
I implemented some code but it's not working - it throws the exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot print a malformed PDF file

Please check my code and let me where I am going wrong.

```cs
internal class CustomPrintDocumentAdapter : PrintDocumentAdapter
{
   private string filePath;
   public CustomPrintDocumentAdapter(string filePath)
   {
      this.filePath = filePath;
   }
   public override void OnLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras)
        {
    if (cancellationSignal.IsCanceled)
    {
        callback.OnLayoutCancelled();
        return;
    }
    callback.OnLayoutFinished(new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(filePath)
    .SetContentType(PrintContentType.Document)
    .Build(), true);
    }

    public override void OnWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback)
    {
        try
        {
        using (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(filePath))
        {
            using (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destination.FileDescriptor))
            {
                var buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buf)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
        callback.OnWriteFinished(new[] { PageRange.AllPages });
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
    {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileNotFoundException);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception);
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: The error says it cannot print a malformed PDF. So it seems that it is an invalid/broken PDF. Try repairing the PDF first and then run your code on the repaired PDF again.

Comment: Hello @Philipp any solution for convert image bitmap to pdf.

Comment: Find a image to pdf converter that supports your image format.